# Rename/Move folder when a process is running from the folder

Tags: c#, directory

I want to Move a folder to another folder.

```
  Directory.Move(OldPath, BackupPath);
  Directory.Move(NewPath, OldPath);
```

The only problem is if I have a process (executable) which was started in one of the folders it can't be renamed like that. Is there a way to force it anyway?

I tried it with:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.MoveDirectory(path, BackupPath)
```

If i try it with Directory.Move following Exception is shown:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.FileSystem.MoveDirectory(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.Move(String sourceDirName, String destDirName)
```

And with VisualBasic.FileIO:

```
   System.IO.IOException: Could not complete operation on some files and directories. See the Data property of the exception for more details.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.FxCopyOrMoveDirectory(CopyOrMove operation, String sourceDirectoryPath, String targetDirectoryPath, Boolean overwrite)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyOrMoveDirectory(CopyOrMove operation, String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationDirectoryName, Boolean overwrite, UIOptionInternal showUI, UICancelOption onUserCancel)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.MoveDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationDirectoryName)
```

Comment: no + bad idea - why would you want to pull the rug out from underneath a process?  you would need to first stop the process.  once stopped you should be good to go

Comment: Yes, it is because the process that is running in the folder does this renaming. And I can't close it because it still has to call other methods.

Comment: check-mate... :-)

Comment: I found a workaround for myself. But it would still be interesting to know whether that somehow works with renaming the folder.
In my case there are two applications in folder. One of them is the main program. That starts my launcher and stops Mainprogram and has to rename folders (if there is a new version.). Now I am making a recursive copy of the folder and overwrite existing files. And if a file cannot be accessed I skip them(must be a launcher file). Then I have the latest version of the main program. And hope that the launcher doesn't need to be updated. : D